# How can I SELECT multiple values from 2 tables? SQL Developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to SELECT `STAFF_ID`, `STAFF_NAME` and `PROJECT_ID`. `STAFF_ID` and `PROJECT_ID` are linked in a table `ASSIGNMENTS`, but I want to show that link while also showing the `STAFF_NAME` for each `STAFF_ID` from the `STAFF` table. Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT
(PROJECT_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PROJECT_NAME CHAR(20),
PROJECT_TYPE CHAR(20),
START_DATE DATE,
END_DATE DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (PROJECT_ID));

CREATE TABLE STAFF
(STAFF_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
STAFF_NAME CHAR(20),
JOB_TYPE CHAR(20),
JOB_GRADE CHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (STAFF_ID));

CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENTS
(ASSIGNMENT_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PROJECT_ID CHAR(5),
STAFF_ID CHAR(5),
PRIMARY KEY (ASSIGNMENT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PROJECT(PROJECT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (STAFF_ID) REFERENCES STAFF(STAFF_ID));
```

All the tables have been populated with data, and this is the query I've used so far which shows which employees work on a given project (but only with STAFF_ID, not with STAFF_NAME included):

```
SELECT STAFF_ID, PROJECT_ID
FROM ASSIGNMENTS
WHERE PROJECT_ID = 'B0005';
```

How can I show the links like this while also including the STAFF_NAME linked to the STAFF_ID from the STAFF table?

Here is some data for a row of each table:

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_TYPE, START_DATE, END_DATE)
VALUES ('B0001','BIKESHOP.COM','WEB DEVELOPMENT',TO_DATE('15/01/17','DD/MM/YY'),TO_DATE('15/02/17','DD/MM/YY'));

INSERT INTO STAFF (STAFF_ID, STAFF_NAME, JOB_TYPE, JOB_GRADE)
VALUES ('ST001','JOHN MASON','WEB DEVELOPER','1');

INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENTS (ASSIGNMENT_ID, PROJECT_ID, STAFF_ID, HARDWARE_ID, SOFTWARE_ID)
VALUES ('A0001','B0001','ST001','H0001','S0001');
```

What I want to show is `PROJECT_ID`, `STAFF_ID`, `STAFF_NAME`. Just three columns showing those 3 values.

Comment: plz Give us some data as input and a desired output.

Comment: Here is a row of data for each table table:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add join to `STAFF` table. Something like this

```
SELECT STAFF.STAFF_ID, STAFF.STAFF_NAME, ASSIGNMENTS.PROJECT_ID
FROM ASSIGNMENTS 
INNER JOIN STAFF ON ASSIGNMENTS.STAFF_ID = STAFF.STAFF_ID 
WHERE ASSIGNMENTS.PROJECT_ID = 'B0005';
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this select can solve your problem

```
select PROJECT_ID, STAFF_ID, STAFF_NAME from ASSIGNMENTS
inner join STAFF on STAFF.STAFF_ID=ASSIGNMENTS.STAFF_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this need, Join the three tables as next approach:

**Generic Syntax:**

```
select *
from
    tableA a
        inner join
    tableB b
        on a.common = b.common
        inner join 
    TableC c
        on b.common = c.common
```

so follow the next query:

```
 select a.PROJECT_ID, b.STAFF_ID, c.STAFF_NAME
 from PROJECT a inner join ASSIGNMENTS b
 on a.PROJECT_ID = b.PROJECT_ID
 inner join STAFF c
 on c.STAFF_ID = b.STAFF_ID
```

**Result:**

[image]